# Leftmost launch bar broken in 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

After going from 16.04 to 18.04 I noticed that there are a few things missing (apart from the obvious lack of the useful Alt+alt menu search)

- I install Netbeans 9 and when I run it, there is no right click and
  lock in launch panel... How do I keep it handy in the leftmost
  launcher? It also has awful simple looking checkboxes and tabs within Netbeans (Java?) but that's another topic.
- Middle scroll doesn't seem to do anything on the leftmost launcher. You used to be able to jump through all the terminal windows or windows of a certain app with the scroll wheel which is very handy.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, otherwise this may be closed as "too broad". Also did you install Unity and using it? Ubuntu 18.04 has GNOME instead of Unity by default.

Comment: Yep using Gnome, it's surprising how features are missing from 18.04 unfortunately.

Comment: I actually just found that today... Thanks though.